# Using the '?' Parameter in SQL LIKE Statement

Tags: sql, excel, parameters, firebird, sql-like

I'm accessing a Firebird database through Microsoft Query in Excel.

I have a parameter field in Excel that contains a 4 digit number. One of my DB tables has a column (`TP.PHASE_CODE`) containing a 9 digit phase code, and I need to return any of those 9 digit codes that start with the 4 digit code specified as a parameter.

For example, if my parameter field contains '8000', I need to find and return any phase code in the other table/column that is `LIKE '8000%'`.

I am wondering how to accomplish this in SQL since it doesn't seem like the '?' representing the parameter can be included in a LIKE statement. (If I write in the 4 digits, the query works fine, but it won't let me use a parameter there.)

The problematic statements is this one:  `TP.PHASE_CODE like '?%'`

Here is my full code:

```
SELECT C.COSTS_ID, C.AREA_ID, S.SUB_NUMBER, S.SUB_NAME, TP.PHASE_CODE, TP.PHASE_DESC,       TI.ITEM_NUMBER, TI.ITEM_DESC,TI.ORDER_UNIT,
C.UNIT_COST, TI.TLPE_ITEMS_ID FROM TLPE_ITEMS TI
INNER JOIN TLPE_PHASES TP ON TI.TLPE_PHASES_ID = TP.TLPE_PHASES_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN COSTS C ON C.TLPE_ITEMS_ID = TI.TLPE_ITEMS_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN AREA A ON C.AREA_ID = A.AREA_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN SUPPLIER S ON C.SUB_NUMBER = S.SUB_NUMBER

WHERE (C.AREA_ID = 1 OR C.AREA_ID = ?) and S.SUB_NUMBER = ? and TI.ITEM_NUMBER = ? and **TP.PHASE_CODE like '?%'**

ORDER BY TP.PHASE_CODE
```

Any ideas on alternate ways of accomplishing this query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `LIKE '?%', then the question mark is literal text, not a parameter placeholder.

You can use `LIKE ? || '%'`, or alternatively if your parameter itself never contains a LIKE-pattern: `STARTING WITH ?` which might be more efficient if the field you're querying is indexed.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks, it seems like Firebird is limited as far as string functions go, but before you answered I did find a "substring" function that did the job as follows:  "substring(TP.PHASE_CODE from 1 for 4) = ?"  (Your solution is a lot simpler though!) Thanks again.

Comment: @user2452582 I am not entirely sure what string functions have to do with your original question. You can find a list of internal functions in http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc.html

Comment: Hi Mark, since I couldn't find the (||) solution that you gave me, I was looking for string functions to use to extract the first 4 digits that I needed to compare the parameter to...

Comment: I had never realised that (`||` is defined by the SQL standard), but a quick peek in the documentation set shows it is listed in the Embedded SQL guide, Table 6.2 (see http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ at the end ). Given the name of that document it might not be the first place you'd look.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
and TP.PHASE_CODE like ?
```

but when you pass your parameter `8000` to the SQL, you have to add the `%` behind it, so in this case, you would pass `"8000%"` to the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try String Functions: [Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)?

> WHERE (C.AREA_ID = 1 OR Left(C.AREA_ID,4) = "8000")